# Where does Django-Channels store user's channel names?

Tags: python, django, websocket, python-asyncio, django-channels

I am trying to add a user to a django channels group but I do not know the user's channel name. Only their database id/username. I have been reading through channels' documentation but was not able to discover where these channel names are stored.

Normally, from within a channel's communicator, I can add the user of the communicator to a group with:

```
class OrderConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, scope): ...

    async def connect(self): ...

    async def add_user_to_group(self, group_name):
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            group=group_name,
            channel=self.channel_name
        )
```

**Is it possible to access another user's "self.channel_name" via the database? or otherwise? If so how?**

---

I am using an InMemoryChannelLayer for my tests:

```
TEST_CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer',
    },
}
```

but a redis database (with the help of channels-redis) in my live deployment. **Will this make a difference?**

Answer (score 3):

As you already discovered, the channel names are assigned by the channel server and there's no way to compute it for a given user. What most people do to keep track of individual user's channel is to add each user to a unique group whose name is generated from the user's DB id or any other unique field. In that way, if you want to send a message to a particular user, you can easily compute his group name from the user's data

Answer (score 0):

`channel_name` is defined in your `routing.py` and `group_name` should be a property in your consumer class:

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    #

    @property
    def group_name(self):
        name = ...
        return name
```

So when a user visits url connected to your websocket you may either decline or accept them in your `connect` method.

Backend implementation choice is irrelevant.

Comment: I still do not understand. Each user that connects to the websocket is given their own unique channel_name. Are you telling me I can see where these are stored  based on my routing.py implementation? Channel_name is not defined anywhere in my routing.py implementation (explicitly by me or in any of the classes I use).

Comment: Then probably I misunderstood you: do you want to add user to a group in some other way instead usual through a consumer upon connect?

Comment: Hi. Yes! I want to add a separate user [user 2] (by which I mean a user with a different consumer to the one being called [user 1]) whose id I know to a group when the user 1 calls a function in the consumer (with user 2's id attached in the data)

I have made a much more detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485030/how-can-i-add-a-user-whose-id-i-know-to-a-django-channels-channel-layer-group?noredirect=1#comment101443735_57485030). I appreciate the time and effort you are spending.

Comment: Well, may I says KISS or even YAGNI? :P Your order is created anyway and you know how to add the buyer to order group (the usual way). Use Django messaging system or whatever else you want to notify store owner of a new order, just create a simple link to the order. After store owner visits the url he would be added to the group and when they leaves the page they automatically will **leave the group** too. That goes for the buyers too - and that's the way how you should deal with websockets, for everything else there's good ol' Django.